# python question print the number of elements which are divisible by a

Tags: python-3.x

my code is    :-

```
list_1 = [i for i in range(1, 51)]
a=int(input())
list_1.remove(a)
count=0
for i in list_1:
    if(i%a==0):
      count=count+1
      print(count)
```

but output come is this way when input is `12` then output come is

```
1
2
3
```

but i need output 3 only  so how to do this please help

Comment: put the `print` statement outside the `for` loop (i.e. no indentation on the last line).

Comment: oh Thank you very must

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum`.

```
sum(x % a == 0 for x in list_1)
```

Since `True == 1` and `False == 0`, this sums to how many times the predicate is true.

Comment: i think it would be conveint for less experienced pythonist to explain True equals to  the integer 1

Answer (score 0):

Break the if statement and use the ending condition i.e.i=50
e.g.

```
    l=list(range(1,51))
    a=int(input())
    count=-1
    for i in l:
        if(i%a==0):
            count=count+1
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(len([i for i in list_1 if i%a == 0]))
```

this creats a list with the divisible numbers, and gets the length of the list. I will also point out that len() is a function of O(1) timecomplexity, meaning only one loop takes place - because of the list comprehension - , and list comprehension tents to be quite fast :)